# .NET CORE how to bind list of objects in viewmodel through partial view popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, partial-views

For my project i need to create schools and add students that learn there. But the school and the students needs to be created in the same view.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPjTL.png]

Example can be seen on the photo. School name should be entered. On the add student button, modal popup will show up where student name and age are entered. After clicking add in the popup user should be added in the list.You can add as many students as you like. At the end when clicking save the school with all students added should be sent to controller in order to save them in database.

Example of the Viewmodels

```
public class SchoolViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Students> Students { get; set; }
}

public class Students
{
    public string StudentsName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

I couldn't figure out a way to add students dynamically to the list and how to bind and store temporary to the schoolviewmodel in order to have their data on the last Save button post method

Comment: You can use a JS variable and save your values into that as JSON , at the end , you post your data to the server.

Comment: Mvc gives you most of this out of the box. https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/build-crud-application-with-asp-net-core-entity-framework-visual-studio-2019.aspx.

Comment: manipulate the dom with hidden inputs for new students data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create a demo which places the popup modal in partial view to enter student's name and age.After entering name and age, click the `Add` button of modal,then it will append input data to the students table in main view.

Finally, send all data using ajax when click the SAVE button.Followings are steps of my demo:

1.Create a partial view in `/Views/Shared/_AddStudentPartial.cshtml`

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Student</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="col-4">
                <label> Student Name</label>
                <input id="tempName" name="tempName" class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-4">
                <label> Student Age</label>
                <input id="tempAge" name="tempAge" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" id="addStudent" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

2.AddSchool.cshtml

```
@model SchoolViewModel
<h1>AddSchool</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form>
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">School Name</label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Student Name
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Student Age
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="studentList"></tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Add Student</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" id="saveSchool" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<partial name="_AddStudentPartial" />

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //append students to table
            $("#studentList").empty();
            $('#addStudent').on('click', function () {
                var name = $('#tempName').val();
                var age = $('#tempAge').val();

                $('<tr><td>' + name + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + age + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>').appendTo($('#studentList'));

                $('#exampleModal').modal('hide');
                document.getElementById("tempName").value = "";
                document.getElementById("tempAge").value = "";
            });

            //save school
            $('#saveSchool').on('click', function () {

                var formData = new FormData();
                var schoolName = $('#Name').val();
                formData.append("name", schoolName);

                $("#studentList tr").each(function (i) {
                    $("td", this).each(function (j) {
                        if (j == 0) {
                            formData.append("Students[" + i + "].StudentsName", $(this).text());
                        } else {
                            formData.append("Students[" + i + "].Age", $(this).text());
                        }
                    });
                });


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/AddSchool",//use your url
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                      //deal with the response
                   }

                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

3.Controller

```
public IActionResult AddSchool()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddSchool(SchoolViewModel schoolViewModel)
{
    //save to database
}
```